# Scheduling Autosys jobs

Tags: unix, autosys

I am tasked with creating Autosys jobs for my monthly processes, but I can't seem to use any of the Autosys commands...

Do I have to be logged into as autoadm user in order to do so, or is there something else I can do ?

thanks.

More Details:

I am trying to create a run_calendar for my jobs.
The command I am trying to use is: autocal_asc

The problem is that I  cant run any of the commands:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -l
total 6224
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        51444 Mar 20  2013 as_config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        99312 Dec  6  2012 as_info
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        34592 Mar 20  2013 as_test
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        10180 Mar 20  2013 astail
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        82124 Mar 20  2013 auto_svcdesk
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       327020 Mar 20  2013 autoaggr
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       182992 Mar 20  2013 autocal_asc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        82452 Mar 20  2013 autoflags
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        62364 Mar 20  2013 autoping
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       381324 Mar 20  2013 autorep
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        55208 Mar 20  2013 autosec_test
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        51544 Mar 20  2013 autostatad
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        42884 Mar 20  2013 autostatus
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       334236 Apr  3  2013 autosys_secure
-r-xr-xr-x   1 waae     sys         9876 Mar 15  2012 autosyslog
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        59236 Mar 20  2013 autotimezone
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        68444 Mar 20  2013 autotrack
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        68480 Mar 20  2013 autouxlog
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        66444 Mar 20  2013 chase
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        68084 Mar 20  2013 chk_auto_up
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        44576 Mar 20  2013 clean_files
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        30788 Mar 20  2013 cron2jil
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       380372 Mar 20  2013 jil
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       153904 Mar 20  2013 job_depends
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       161268 Mar 20  2013 monbro
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys       115856 Mar 20  2013 sendevent
-r-xr-xr-x   1 waae     sys         1833 Aug  6  2003 template
-rwxr-xr-x   1 waae     sys        44796 Mar 20  2013 time0
bash-3.2$



bash-3.2$ . autocal_asc
bash:ELF: command not found

bash-3.2$ ./autocal_asc
ld.so.1: autocal_asc: fatal: libascmn.so: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed
```

Comment: Which commands are you trying to run? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question, its a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to start the autosys agent before I could run commands:

```
$ bash
bash-3.2$ . /opt/CA/autouser/autosys.sh.servername
```